# Prove $\operatorname{Corr}(X,\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y)) > 0$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, correlation

Well, the exercise tell me:

> Be $X$ and $Y$ r.v with $\mathbb{E}(X) = \mathbb{E}(Y) = 0$. Prove that $\operatorname{Corr}(X,\mathbb{E}(X\mid\sigma(Y))) \geq 0$

Well my idea is the following:

$\operatorname{Corr}(X,\mathbb{E}(X\mid\sigma(Y))) = \mathbb{E}(X \cdot \mathbb{E}(X\mid\sigma(Y))) - \mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X\mid\sigma(Y))) = \mathbb{E}(X \cdot \mathbb{E}(X \mid \sigma(Y)))$ because $\mathbb{E}(X) = 0$.

From here I don't know how can I prove what they ask to me. My idea to continue my solution is to assume that $X$ is $\sigma(Y)$ measurable so $\mathbb{E}(X \mid \sigma(Y)) = X$ and then we will have that $\operatorname{Corr}(X,\mathbb{E}(X\mid\sigma(Y))) = \mathbb{V}(X) \geq 0$.

My problem is that I don't know if I can assume that $X$ is $\sigma (Y)$ measurable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might rely on the fact that $E[X|Y]$ is $\sigma(Y)$ measurable, so:
$$\textrm{Cov}[X,E[X|Y]]=E[E[X|Y]X]=E[E[E[X|Y]X|Y]]=E[E[X|Y]^2]\geq 0$$

Comment: But why can I assume that $\mathbb{E}(X|Y))$ is $\sigma(Y)$ measurable?

Comment: @Julian It is by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_sub-%CF%83-algebra)

Comment: Oh yes its true, I was thinking about $X$ being $\sigma(Y)$ measurable

Comment: But, what do you use to pass from $E[E[X|Y]X]=E[E[E[X|Y]X|Y]]$

Comment: @Julian law of total expectation